# Remix app throws 'process is not defined' error in client due to 'pg' node module

Tags: node.js, postgresql, remix.run

In my Remix app, which is also a Shopify app, I am making a PostgreSQL query using the `pg` node module in a loader function. The server successfully performs the query and gets a response from the database. However, the client throws an error of `process is not defined`. This is being caused by the `pg` node module outlined in the source below.

As far as I know, server side modules should not make their way to the client?

Viewing the client source highlights the error when it attempts to access `process.env.USERNAME` on the line `user: process.platform === "win32" ? process.env.USERNAME : process.env.USER` as shown below.

```
// node_modules/.pnpm/pg@8.11.3/node_modules/pg/lib/defaults.js
var require_defaults = __commonJS({
  "node_modules/.pnpm/pg@8.11.3/node_modules/pg/lib/defaults.js"(exports11, module2) {
    "use strict";
    module2.exports = {
      // database host. defaults to localhost
      host: "localhost",
      // database user's name
      user: process.platform === "win32" ? process.env.USERNAME : process.env.USER,

      // rest of source...
```

My code:

```
// app._index.jsx

import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import ShopDAO from '~/dao/shopDAO';

export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
  const auth = await authenticate.admin(request);
  const shopName = auth.session.shop;
  const data = await ShopDAO.read(shopName);

  return json(data);
};

export default function Index() {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <p>Index</p>
  );
}
```

```
// shopDAO.js

import pool from "~/db/db";

class ShopDAO {
  async read(shopName) {
    const query = `
      SELECT * FROM shop WHERE name = $1;
    `;

    try {
      const { rows } = await pool.query(query, [shopName]);
      return rows[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Could not read shop: ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

export default new ShopDAO;
```

I have tried removing the `useLoaderData()` hook from the client (out of interest) and it still results in the same error.

Obviously, the client should not be receiving server side code. So I've either done something wrong, or I've probably done something wrong. I just can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Remix does try to tree-shake any server code out of your client bundles. However, depending on the code, it may not always be possible to do it automatically.

Looking at your code, I have a feeling it is due to:

```js
// shopDA.js
import pool from "~/db/db";
```

Change the filename to `db.server.js` and Remix will ensure that any exports will be server-side only.

Comment: Ah of course. That's got it. Thank's a lot!